# How to make floated list items go down instead of being push aside when previous elements don't have the same height?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The following is what I currently have ...
[image]

... but when you add extra text in one of the items you get this...
[image]

...elements get pushed aside making the list visually ugly. I want to achieve the following:
[image]

I want every "line" of photos to be aligned.

I'm using bootstrap. This gallery should be responsive and I'm looking for a CSS-only solution since I don't want to add extra/non-semantic HTML.

Codepen: http://codepen.io/nunoarruda/pen/vExBxN

```
.gallery {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.gallery li {
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}

.gallery a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.gallery img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.post-txt {
  display: block;
  background-color: #01558d;
  font-family: 'Voces', cursive;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 4px 8px;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You might be able to do this more easily using `display: inline-block` on your `li` elements instead of floats.  I am not sure if Bootstrap will let you to this.  I could propose a non-Bootstrap solution if that helps.

Comment: @MarcAudet please do!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Using Inline-Blocks**

Here is one way of doing it.

The key is to use `display: inline-block` on the `li` element, and apply `vertical-align: top` to get the top edges to line up.

You also need to assign a width, I used `width: 20%` for demonstration.  I am not sure if this will give you the control that you need for your layout, but you are the best judge of that.

Anyway, at least this can get you started.

```css
.gallery {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.gallery li {
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 20%;
}

.gallery a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.gallery img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.post-txt {
  display: block;
  background-color: #01558d;
  font-family: 'Voces', cursive;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 4px 8px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="row gallery">
  <li class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3"><a href="#"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/peoplejar-production/assets/12395/original/post-image.jpg?1419981725"><span class="post-txt">Family out tailgating and more text</span></a></li>
  <li class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3"><a href="#"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/peoplejar-production/assets/12395/original/post-image.jpg?1419981725"><span class="post-txt">Family out tailgating</span></a></li>
  <li class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3"><a href="#"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/peoplejar-production/assets/12395/original/post-image.jpg?1419981725"><span class="post-txt">Family out tailgating</span></a></li>
  <li class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3"><a href="#"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/peoplejar-production/assets/12395/original/post-image.jpg?1419981725"><span class="post-txt">Family out tailgating</span></a></li>
  <li class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3"><a href="#"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/peoplejar-production/assets/12395/original/post-image.jpg?1419981725"><span class="post-txt">Family out tailgating</span></a></li>
  <li class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3"><a href="#"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/peoplejar-production/assets/12395/original/post-image.jpg?1419981725"><span class="post-txt">Family out tailgating</span></a></li>
  <li class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3"><a href="#"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/peoplejar-production/assets/12395/original/post-image.jpg?1419981725"><span class="post-txt">Family out tailgating</span></a></li>
  <li class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3"><a href="#"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/peoplejar-production/assets/12395/original/post-image.jpg?1419981725"><span class="post-txt">Family out tailgating</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That would be the perfect solution if I was not using Bootstrap. Thanks for the effort!

Comment: You need to override the float property to allow inline-blocks to work.  I am not sure why Bootstrap would prevent you from implementing inline-blocks.

Comment: I gave it a second try and you're right! This is the easiest way of doing it. You need to account for the extra spacing inline-block elements have though. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The easiest CSS-only solution is to simply apply `clear: left;` on every first element in row, dependly on window size:

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .gallery li:nth-child(3n) {
    clear: left;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .gallery li:nth-child(5n) {
    clear: left;
  }
}
```

**Demo:** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogZNvL

Comment: That would work if the gallery was fixed width. I need it to be responsive. Thanks for the effort anyways.

Comment: It is responsive. Are you using IE8?

Comment: No. Resize you're browser to lower widths to see what I mean (check when it's "rows" of 2 photos). I can't use `clear: left;` on every 5th element because is not always the 5th element that's below the one with more text.

Comment: I see now, my bad, I thought it's always 4 elements. The easiest way I see is to use @media directives. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Your example still breaks in certain browser widths but I see you're point. I'm going to try it.

Comment: Yes, due to margins the border seems to be 767px - replace 800px with it and you're good to go.

Comment: Two solutions I can think of, both easy. First is to implement above CSS, and at breakpoint, reset the `nth-child(5n)` to `clear: none`, and apply the `clear: left` to the `nth-child(3n)`. Second is to use different rows to contain the elements.

Comment: I've edited the code for a final version that works perfectly! Although I did accept Marc's solution because its the easier way of doing it. Thanks for all the effort!

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to position the `span` as `absolute` (contained by it's parent `a`) set to `bottom: 0`. That way the overflow of text will go upwards instead of down:

```
.gallery a {
   display: block;
   color: #fff;
   text-decoration: none;
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
}

.post-txt {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   display: block;
   background-color: #01558d;
   font-family: 'Voces', cursive;
   font-size: 11px;
   font-weight: bold;
   padding: 4px 8px;
   word-break: break-word;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[**EXAMPLE 1**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qErBBb)

## **OR**

You can use a css version of truncating:

```
.post-txt {
   width: 100%;
   display: block;
   background-color: #01558d;
   font-family: 'Voces', cursive;
   font-size: 11px;
   font-weight: bold;
   padding: 4px 8px;
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

[**EXAMPLE 2**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bNqGGM)

## **OR**

Combine the two: use ellipsis and on hover show the rest:

```
.post-txt {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  background-color: #01558d;
  font-family: 'Voces', cursive;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
 }

 .gallery li a:hover .post-txt{
    overflow: visible;
    text-overflow: none;
    white-space: normal;
    position: absolute;
 }
```

[**EXAMPLE 3**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bNqGGM)

Comment: Example 3 is neat and cleaver! Could be a solution for me if the character limit is low.

Comment: im guessing the text will be dynamically entered? You could always put a limit on how much can be typed

Answer (score 1):

This was done very quick and is untested.
It will set all image divs to the same height.
Set the id for each image div to:

```
id="imgX"
```

Where X = 1-8 (for 8 images)

```
var max = 0;
var did,len;
img = new Array;
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for (var div=0; div<divs.length; div++){
  did = divs[div].getAttribute("id");
  if (did != null && did.substring(0,3) == "img"){
    img[].push(div);
    len = divs[div].offsetHeight;
    if (len > max)(max = len;}

  }
  for (var div=0; div<img.length; div++){
    divs[img[div]].style.height= (max+ 'px');
  }
}
```

**For CSS solution see:**

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks